# Which is correct "What does this mean or what does this means"

Tags: word-usage

Please help me understand when should the plural forms be used... 
Ex. What does this mean or what does this means .. 
       He rides well or he ride well etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What does this mean?", "This means something."

"Mean(s)", as in attempting to convey meaning, is "Mean" where referring to yourself ("I mean"), referring to a group of people including or not including yourself ("We mean", "They mean"), or referring to someone else in the gender-neutral. ("They mean")

For all other purposes, "means" would be applicable: referring to someone else in the singular gender-specific form ("He means" or "She means"), referring to an object ("It means"), referring to something in or out of posession("This means" or "That means"), and so on.

This is generally the case with English verbs. I wouldn't call this singular/plural forms.

Comment: So the correct usage would be ..what does this means? Right

Comment: No, "mean" would be used following "this" - "What does this mean?"

Answer (score 3):

"What does this means" is wrong. The verb "mean" should remain in the infinitive because the auxiliary verb "do" is already conjugated. That happens with all verbs that are used together with an auxiliary verb in questions and in the negative in simple present and simple past tenses. In those cases, only the auxiliary is conjugated and the main verb remains in the infinitive.